# Issues embedding php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a PHP file that I am using to display HTML and grab data from a database, I want to grab the data when the page is loaded, store it in javascript arrays then access it later via an onchange event. The database has been tested and works however I am having issues getting the data from PHP to JS, I have read all the other topics and none of those suggestions seem to help.

Here is the error when checked in chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

this error is on the following line

```
var myAge = <?php echo json_encode($phpAge); ?>;
```

I hope the explains all, I can post all the code if its needed.

Comment: WE need to see your code to fix it.  Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data from PHP to JavaScript, you need to escape it properly.  The best way to do this is with `json_encode()`.

```
<?php
$data = array('someKey' => 'someValue');
echo 'var data = ', json_encode($data), ';';
```

The output of this script will be valid JavaScript.

```
var data = {"someKey": "someValue"};
```

Also note that if you wish to process JavaScript files as PHP, you need to configure your server to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply dump a serialized JSON string in the middle of your JavaScript code and assume it will work. It has to be declared as a proper string, with quotation marks around it, escaped symbols etc.

A proper way of doing that would be something more like this:

```
<?php
    echo "var data = \"" . addslashes(json_encode($phpAge)) . "\";\r\n";
?>
```

Or this way if you prefer:

```
var myAge = "<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($phpAge)); ?>";
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect.  Do not use `addslashes()` around something that has already been encoded as JSON.  The JSON encoding will take care of formatting the data in the correct way.  All you're doing is sticking a string containing JSON data into a JavaScript variable.

Comment: @Brad And thats exactly why `addslashes()` is important there. I'm not passing JSON to the JavaScript, I'm passing a string with the JSON inside. If I'd just take your exemple and put with "" around it, it would be `var data = "{"someKey": "someValue"}"`, and as you can see its invalid. It must be `var data = "{\"someKey\": \"someValue\"}"`

Comment: Yes, that is my point!  Drop the quotes around it, and get rid of `addslashes()`.  The object will be just fine when not sent as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysqli, maybe something like this would help you?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');
        $res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM table_name');
        $data = array();
        while($fld = $res->fetch_assoc()) { $data[] = $fld; }
        echo('var data = ' . json_encode($data) . ';');
    ?>
</script>
```

If you then go to console (F12 in Chrome) and type in `data` and press return, it should show the localised version of your data.